# form to input event.title to show it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, activerecord, bootstrap-4

I want to make a **form in navbar**, where a user has to input `event.title` to go to event/show.

It should look like this:

[image: enter event title]

The form code:

```
  %form.form-inline
    %input.form-control.mr-sm-2{"aria-label" => "Search", :placeholder => "Enter Event Title", :type => "search"}/
    %button.btn.btn-outline-dark{:type => "submit"} Join!
```

How can I acomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can accomplish this using Rails [form_with](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with):

```
<%= form_with url: event_path do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Enter Event Title', class: 'form-control mr-sm-2' %>
  <%= form.submit 'Join!', class: 'btn btn-outline-dark' %>
<% end %>
```

Events Controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  # This is an example how to access params[:title]
  def show
    @example = Event.create(params[:title])
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :events, only: [:show]
```

The above is an example how to accomplish this. Build a Rails form in your view that passes the `title` to your show route. Make sure you have your routes setup and update your styles.

Comment: what does `@example` in `EventsController` stand for? If I add the code, I get `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events"}, missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: It is an example of how to accomplish your question. Its not necessarily a copy/paste answer..